# How to grab all files from Azure Blob and Zip them?

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Blob with many containers. Each container has multiple folders - and each folder has a bunch of files in it. I want to be able to grab all of the files and return them zipped. I'm currently only able to get one file at a time...

```
public void downloadAllFromBlob(String containerName){
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = this.storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
    try{
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
        
        if(container.exists()){
             // I want to grab all the files in the container and zip them
            for(ListBlobItem blobItem: container.listBlobs()){
                   // i'm only able to list/VIEW the blobs, and not go into one and get all the contents
            }
         }

     }catch(){
     }
}
```

Comment: there isn't any API available but you can use az command-line tool. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-batch

Comment: @Manish I was able to do this - why are no API's available for this yet the CLI tool does?

Comment: there is one API available in beta called batch but I didn't check what it does. but you can create a background service using CLI tools.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no batch retrieve capability available in Azure Blob Storage. You need need to download each blob individually as you showed above. You can try to retrieve blobs in parallel to speed things up.

Comment: I was able to use the Azure CLI to batch download, like here -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-batch . You'd think there would be some Azure SDK feature which can do this same thing....maybe I can intercept the request and just use the same one in my application?